# What is multiset equivalent in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to convert one Oracle syntax to snowflake.
Which is like "table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by level <= length(regexp_replace('ABC-EFG-E','[^;]+')) +1 as sys.odciNumberList)) levels"

Could someone please help me with this conversion.

Answer (score 1):

um, I would say either seqX or generator, depending on what you really need:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/seq1.html
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator.html

please note that seqX results are not guaranteed to be sequential and to get real sequence you'll need to apply row_number()

as far as random strings go it's not gonna be too extensive, you can get:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/randstr.html

but that's about it I'm afraid...

Comment: Hi @MMV, Its not working. Is there any other alternative way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: can you explain what you're trying to achieve? sorry, don't really have oracle installed so I can't run your code and see

Comment: I am trying to calculate the length from regexp and then connect by the level of the table.

Comment: Thanks @MMV, I was able to fix the issue. Using generator, casting is taken care by snowflake internally so removed that too from query.

Answer (score 0):

Post the Equivalent in snowflake , how you have acheived and kindly post the query in snowflake ..so that it will be useful for others

Comment: Hi Lesly,What I did was. Removed everything as above in question and replaced it with "(select seq4() as column_val from table(generator ())) levels where column_val <=length (regexp_replace('ABC-EFG-E','[^;]+')) +1"